# CSS is getting applied to above section

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm having an issue were the CSS that I'm applying to a React component, is getting applied to the component above it.

See the example below:

```
|------------|
|  Section 1 | CSS getting applied here
|------------|
|  Section 2 | CSS code is in this component
|------------|
```

Here is a sample of the code in the component:

```css
.area{
    background: #4e54c8;  
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to left, #8f94fb, #4e54c8);  
    width: 100%;
    height:100vh;
}

.circles{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.circles li{
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    list-style: none;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    animation: animate 25s linear infinite;
    bottom: -150px;
    
}

.circles li:nth-child(1){
    left: 25%;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    animation-delay: 0s;
}


.circles li:nth-child(2){
    left: 10%;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    animation-delay: 2s;
    animation-duration: 12s;
}

.circles li:nth-child(3){
    left: 70%;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    animation-delay: 4s;
}

.circles li:nth-child(4){
    left: 40%;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    animation-delay: 0s;
    animation-duration: 18s;
}

.circles li:nth-child(5){
    left: 65%;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    animation-delay: 0s;
}

.circles li:nth-child(6){
    left: 75%;
    width: 110px;
    height: 110px;
    animation-delay: 3s;
}

.circles li:nth-child(7){
    left: 35%;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    animation-delay: 7s;
}

.circles li:nth-child(8){
    left: 50%;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    animation-delay: 15s;
    animation-duration: 45s;
}

.circles li:nth-child(9){
    left: 20%;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    animation-delay: 2s;
    animation-duration: 35s;
}

.circles li:nth-child(10){
    left: 85%;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    animation-delay: 0s;
    animation-duration: 11s;
}



@keyframes animate {

    0%{
        transform: translateY(0) rotate(0deg);
        opacity: 1;
        border-radius: 0;
    }

    100%{
        transform: translateY(-1000px) rotate(720deg);
        opacity: 0;
        border-radius: 50%;
    }

}
```

```html
<div class="area">
  <ul class="circles">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but I cannot see how to fix it. I'm trying to use the example [here](https://codepen.io/mohaiman/pen/MQqMyo) as a reference.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You didn't really state what the desired outcome should be. :)

Comment: Seems like your code is working as the example you were referring to

Comment: If you're just using regular CSS, it will apply to anywhere in the DOM that matches the selector, regardless of which component loaded it. If you want to isolate CSS to a component I'd suggest looking into "css modules" (or as a quicker but less reliable solution, manually prefixing your selectors with a module name)

Comment: Most likely a scoping issue, like DBS mentioned, look at css modules or a library like Styled Components that allows you to scope your css to your components with a “CSS-in-JS” method. Keep styles with a global scope in a stylesheet loaded globally, for short component specific styles, any “CSS-in-JS” method works well. Some components require a lot more css, at this point may be better to separate concerns into a separate stylesheet associated with that component (css module), here you can write using standard css syntax as well. You have options, go with what suits your needs.